# js runs on even times of modal opening

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange issue. Maybe someone has encountered similar case. I have a modal window having a dual select list that pops up by a button click. List items can not be selected (activated by mouse click) on the 1st, 3th, 5th.. times of modal opening but selected only on the 2nd, 4th, 6th.. times of modal opening. I wonder if it is a js conflict issue. Any help will be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
@model IEnumerable<MajorAdmin.ViewModel.DList>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<div class=""> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_content">
                    <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>

                                    <td>
                                        <a>@item.ev</a>
                                    </td>


                                    <td>
                                        <a id="@item.id" name="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editpartialmodaldiv" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="editpartialmodaldiv" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"></div>


</div>


<script src="~/Content/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

      $("a[name='edit']").click(function () {

        var selectedid = this.id;

        var data = JSON.stringify({
            'selecteditem': selectedid,
        });

              jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetID")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: data,
                success: function (json) {
                  $("#editpartialmodaldiv").load('@Url.Action("Edit")');

                   },
                failure: function (errMsg) {
                    alert(data);
                }
        });
    });



</script>
```

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">

      <div role="main">
        <div class="">

          <div class="clearfix"></div>


          <div class="dual-list list-left col-md-5">
            <div class="well text-right">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    <input type="text" name="SearchDualList" class="form-control" placeholder="search" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-default selector" title="select all"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <ul id="sortable1" class="list-group">
                @foreach (var item in Model) { if (item.evl == null) {
                <li class="list-group-item"><img src="~/Content/images/img.jpg" class="avatar" style="max-height:30px" alt="Avatar">@item.emp</li>
                } }
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="list-arrows col-md-1 text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-left">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-right">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="dual-list list-right col-md-5">
            <div class="well">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-default selector" title="select all"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="SearchDualList" class="form-control" placeholder="search" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <ul id="sortable2" class="list-group text-right">
                @foreach (var item in Model) { if (item.emp == null) {
                <li class="list-group-item"><img src="~/Content/images/img.jpg" class="avatar" style="max-height:30px" alt="Avatar">@item.evaluator</li>
                } }
              </ul>


            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="clearfix"></div>


    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button id="savebutton" name="formsavebutton" value="Create" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="~/Content/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Dual List Scripts -->
<script src="~/Content/js/duallist/duallist.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] using RENDERED html and working code - click the `<>` snippet editor

Comment: your snippet is not really verifiable as it doesn't have any of the JS behaviour we are supposed to check (duallist.js is not loaded, of course, and we don't know what's inside). I personnally would bet on a selector that doesn't work 1 time on 2 because a class is toggled

Comment: yes it toggles on duallist.js  ==>  $('body').on('click', '.list-group .list-group-item', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Thanks to @Kaddath..

I added toggle function to return success of ajax response ==> $('body').on('click', '.list-group .list-group-item', function () {
                      $(this).toggleClass('active');